# Code giving wrong index in list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, substring

I am trying to search through a list of strings for specific substring. Strange thing is 'start' works and gives correct index, while 'end' gives an index about 39 indexes after correct index.

```
file = open(fileName, 'r')
trimmedText = file.readlines()
file.close()

start = [i for i, line in enumerate(trimmedText) if '*** START OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK' in line]
end = [i for i, line in enumerate(trimmedText) if '*** END OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK' in line]
```

Comment: Could you also share the content of `trimmedText` or of the file?

Comment: the file is an entire book with over 20000 elements and only has one iteration of these lines in it

Comment: you're saying that `print([trimmedText[i] for i in end])` doesn't give lines with `'END OF ...'` in it?

Comment: `print([trimmedText[i] for i in end])` gives `['*** END OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK HISTORY OF AUSTRALIAN EXPLORATION ***\n']` while `print(end)` gives wrong index

Comment: @MatiasJoaHauge - Could you reduce it to a minimum working example?

Comment: How are you determining the "correct index" of the 'end' line?  If you're just looking at line numbers in a text editor, perhaps the editor is breaking long lines into two, or not properly handling inconsistent line endings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to want the first hit for the start, and then the first hit for the end I would suggest using the enumerated list in generator expressions:

```
trimmedList = ['ham', 'eggs', 'European swallow', 'spammy spammity spam', 'spamelot', 'spam in a can', 'bacon']
enum_trimmed = enumerate(trimmedList)
start = next(i for (i, words) in enum_trimmed if 'eggs' in words)
end = next(i for (i, words) in enum_trimmed if 'spam' in words)
start, end
(1, 3)
```

You gain the advantage that you advance through the lines only far enough to find the start tag, and then keep going only until you find the end tag.